# iCloud keychain authorisation sends sms to old number

Tags: iphone, icloud, keychain

I want to set up iCloud keychain on my apple devices. To do so I went to settings > iCloud > keychain and turned it on and a button 'Approve with security code' appeared. It asked my iCloud security code and after it asks for 6 digit verification code that has been sent to my old phone number that I no longer have access to. After trying to find where I can change my number. I already went to settings > phone > my number and entered my current number but the phone still has sends the verification code to the old number.
I am using an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1

Also tried to set it up on the a macbook with Yosemite but it also send the verification code to the old number.

Comment: Thanks 

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155740/answer/submit

Comment: I changed the no this way too and after restarting the phone and trying the verification process again the new number did receive the security code. Only now it won't accept or remember me adding the sent security code. But at least I was able to change the mobile number. Approving form another device after choosing forgot code did not get me a request on my Mac somehow either. Odd..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calling their support on the phone and a staff member changed it for me. Easy solution if you can get through the customer queue

Answer (score 7):

1. On your iPhone, go to Settings → iCloud → Keychain and switch Keychain off then on again.
2. Tap "Approve with Security Code", tap "Forgot Code" and then tap "Reset".
3. Follow the instructions to reset iCloud keychain and create a new passcode.

   You will then be prompted to update to your new number.

Comment: Tried it actually, to do it I had to call up the Apple Support and verify with security questions and they deleted my old number so I could input my new one

Answer (score 3):

on your iphone 
 - Setting > iCloud > Keychain

- Approve with security code
- on the passcode step, click 'forgot code' and then click 'reset'

follow on screen step, you will be able to update your phone number.
hope these help

Comment: The problem is after I go to iCloud > keychain it asks for my Apple ID password to turn keychain on and after it shows my old number partly hidden and offers to send verification to it or a button 'don't have access to it' which leads to FAQ for the keychain and I could not find my problem there

Answer (score 0):

Login into https://appleid.apple.com/ and you will be able to change under `Phone Numbers`.

Comment: I have changed the number to my current one. But the validation code is still being sent to the old one.

Comment: Is you past phone still registered on your [Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com)?

Comment: both numbers under Phone numbers are my current ones